# Reference Request: Compact subgroups of p-adic Reductive Groups

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups

First, I'd like to understand what the compact open subgroups of $H(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ are, where $H$ is an inner form of $GL_n$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Second, I'd like to know where I can read about this for other reductive groups.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "inner form of $GL_n(Q_p)$"? "inner form of $GL_n$ over $Q_p$" makes sense (in case it's what you mean), not what is written.

Comment: I assume you don't really mean to ask for *all* the compact open subgroups, but only the interesting ones; in which case what you want is the Moy–Prasad theory, as first expounded in http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1253198 and http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1371680 .  A much more user-friendly introduction appears in Joe Rabinoff's lovely [senior thesis](http://math.harvard.edu/~rabinoff/misc/building.pdf).

Comment: @LSpice which ones deserve being called "interesting"? those whose intersection with $SL_n(Q_p)$ are maximal?

Comment: You should maybe specify the question? the compact open subgroups are what they are...

Comment: For the question in the title (that is *all* compact subgroups), see Richard Pink, Compact subgroups of linear algebraic groups, J. Algebra 206 (1998), no. 2,
438-504.

Comment: For maximal compacts, you must catch some Bruhat-Tits theory.

Comment: Marco Maculan prove this year the maximality of hyperspecial subgroups avoiding Bruhat-Tits, in any case you want to avoid it while understanding why hyperspecial subgroups are interesting : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02449v2.pdf

Comment: @YCor, I use 'interesting' in a non-technical sense (although the technical sense is easy to state:  "arising from the MP construction"!), but at least to include those that I have seen arise in a systematic way in representation theory; for example, the maximal compact and its standard filtration subgroups, and the Iwahori subgroup and its filtration subgroups.  In particular, not all of these subgroups are maximal upon intersection with the derived group.

Comment: Pink's paper, referenced by @UriBader:  [author's version](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~pink/ftp/LastVersion.pdf), [journal version](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869398974397), [MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1637068).

Comment: @LSpice this was my point: "interesting" depends on the point of view and of the motivation. I can't tell from the (vague) question if your representation-theoretic point of view is the only good one.

Comment: @KConrad pointed out that my [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257275/reference-request-compact-subgroups-of-p-adic-reductive-groups#comment634206_257275) is no longer working, and supplied an [updated link to Rabinoff's thesis](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~jrabinoff6/papers/building.pdf).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get compact subgroups by taking compact-open subgroups of algebraic subgroups. My understanding is that they are more-or-less all compact subs, e.g. any compact subgroup $H$ should have a finite index subgroup of this form.

Uri Bader's reference to Pink's 1998 paper is a good start. Pink proves this sort of rigidity theorem over a local field of positive characteristic. I believe he should explain why it is "eazzzy" over a local field of zero characteristic but I have no intention of checking it: no pink till Xmas!

Comment: Your "should" in the first paragraph is true: for a smooth affine group $G$ over the fraction field $k$ of a discrete valuation ring $O$, any bounded subgroup $K$ of $G(k)$ lies in a bounded *open* subgroup (maybe also for rank-1 valuation rings?). Indeed, realizing $G$ as a *closed* $k$-subgroup scheme of some GL$_n$, $G(k)$ is topologically a closed subgroup of GL$_n(k)$ and bounded subsets of $G(k)$ are bounded in GL$_n(k)$. That reduces us to the case of GL$_n$ in place of $G$. Clearly $L := K.O^n \subset c O^n$ for some $c\in k^{\times}$, so $L$ is finite free and $K\subset {\rm{GL}}(L)$.

Comment: What does "compact-open subgroup of algebraic subgroups" mean (if not just a compact, open subgroup of the group of rational points, which is the kind of object that we are trying to describe)?